# multiple update query mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in which primary key is combination of two columns. I want to update multiple rows depending upon my Primary keys

```
StationId   ServerDate          Status
1           2011-05-05 01:00:00 0
1           2011-05-06 01:00:00 1
2           2011-05-05 01:00:00 2
```

My update queries currently look like

```
Update data set status = 1 where StationId = '1' and  ServerDate = '2011-05-05 01:00:00'
Update data set status = 2 where StationId = '1' and  ServerDate = '2011-05-06 01:00:00'
```

I was thinking of using [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement but couldn't figure on how to use it when key is combination of two keys. This is the query I wrote using [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html). Its changing all my rows. If a current record doesn't come under any when condition like record 3, its changed to default value 0. I want that record to retain previous value.

```
UPDATE data set status = CASE 
   WHEN StationId = '1' and  ServerDate = '2011-05-05 01:00:00' THEN 1 
   WHEN StationId = '1' and  ServerDate = '2011-05-06 01:00:00' THEN 2 
END
```

Answer (score 3):

> This is the query I wrote using CASE but I got errors in query

Remove the "CASE" after the END keyword and it should be fine:

```
UPDATE data 
   SET status = 
     CASE 
       WHEN stationId = '1' and ServerDate = '2011-05-05 01:00:00' THEN 1 
       WHEN stationId = '1' and ServerDate = '2011-05-06 01:00:00' THEN 2 
       WHEN stationId = '2' and ServerDate = '2011-05-05 01:00:00' THEN 3
     END
WHERE stationId IN ('1', '2')
  AND ServerDate in ('2011-05-05 01:00:00', '2011-05-06 01:00:00')
```

Comment: For records which don't come under any WHEN case are set to default. How do I stop that?

Comment: In that case what if I need to update records for two different StationIds like record 2 and record 3, then what should I do?

Comment: You have to add the condition to the where and move the check for the station id back to the CASE statement. See my edit, you need to change the WHERE condition to reflect what you really want to update. My example might not be want you want.

Comment: You could have a limiting clause for Ids in your case statement and a where clause to prevent edits to non specified Ids

Comment: @Jan S The problem is I want some ServerDate for one Id edited and another same ServerDate not edited for another Id. If you could write a query editing records 2 and record 3 and not record 1 from my example it will be much helpful

Comment: @GunjanNigam : So you want to update status and Server date?  or just server date?

Comment: Just status for StationId 1 ServerDate 2011-05-06 01:00:00 and StationId 2 ServerDate 2011-05-05 01:00:00 but not for StationId 1 ServerDate 2011-05-05 01:00:00

Comment: I'm sure you can adjust my example to support that requirement.

Comment: I don't want to update StationId 1 ServerDate 2011-05-05 01:00:00 . In your example you used a WHEN case for that StationId 1 ServerDate 2011-05-05 01:00:00. I want to retain its old value, whatever it was. If I remove the When case for this case, the where clause will still cover this case. How to remove this case from where clause as well

Comment: @GunjanNigam You should read up on SQL query writing. You should be able to modify my query or the above query to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be: (EDITED)

```
UPDATE data set status = 
(
   CASE 
       WHEN StationId = '1' AND ServerDate = '2011-05-05 01:00:00' THEN 1 
       WHEN StationId = '2' AND ServerDate = '2011-05-06 01:00:00' THEN 2 
    END 
)
WHERE StationId IN ('1','2')
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove your last "CASE"

```
UPDATE data set status = CASE 
   WHEN StationId = '1' and  ServerDate = '2011-05-05 01:00:00' THEN 1 
   WHEN StationId = '1' and  ServerDate = '2011-05-06 01:00:00' THEN 2 
END
```

Comment: Yaa I got that error removed now. The manual at [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) had CASE in the end. Now I have another problem. I have edited my question. Have a look

Answer (score 0):

you can make StationId your index for faster query when you handle multiple rows.

```
mysql>CREATE INDEX index_name ON tableName(StationId);
```

Comment: Since StationId and ServerDate are combined primary key I don't think I need to index my StationId. I will always be searching using a combination of StationId and ServerDate. And I don't want to update in multiple steps. I want to update using one query only